# How to upgrade my arangodb docker container from 2.3.4 to 2.4.0

Tags: arangodb

I am new to these docker concepts, can any one help me on this.

I have installed arangodb docker container from below steps,

First I cloned the Repository(https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-docker) and then did below steps

1. `docker build -t arangodb`
2. `docker create -p 8529:8529 --name arangodb arangodb:latest`

Currently arangodb version I have is 2.3.4

How can I upgrade 2.3.4 to 2.4.0 version ?

Do I need to build the image with latest changes(pulling from repository) and then create the container ? If I do like this , I think it will create new container with latest version . But I want to upgrade the existing container so that I can remain have all my previous data(collections and what not).

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Did you use `host directories` or a `data container`? (https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-docker#persistent-data for more information)

Answer (score 3):

ArangoDB use the volume `/data` as database directory to store the collection data and the volume `/apps` as apps directory to store any extensions. These directory are marked as docker volumes.

You have two possibilities to upgrade your arangodb docker container to the next version:

1. Using host directories
2. Using a data container
   (see: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-docker#persistent-data)

If you use one of the two possibilities you can easily upgrade without losing data